# Use Require instead of import in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

How to use 'require' from older version of react-native  instead of the import in the new versions

Answer (score 1):

If you export your module like this: `module.exports = moduleName;` You should import using `var moduleName = require('moduleName');`

If export your module using `export default moduleName`. You should import using `import ModuleName from './ModuleName;`